# Include remote forwarding in SSH ProxyCommand

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

So I have 3 servers:

- server_a: my target server
- server_b: a jump server
- server_c: another server

Neither server_a or server_b normally have access to server_c at all. However I can use the magic of remote forwarding to provide server_c with a specific port on server_a. The following command accomplishes this:

`ssh -t -A -R 6880:server_c:22 server_b ssh -t -A -R 6880:localhost:6880 server_a`

I want to convert this bulky command into equivalant ssh_config settings. I can get the basic ssh/scp connection working through the use of a proxy command:

```
host server_b
  Hostname 192.X.X.X
  User john
  IdentityFile /path/to/identity_file
  ForwardAgent yes

Host server_a
  Hostname 172.X.X.X
  User john
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server_b
```

But the above configs don't do any remote forwarding, and server_a doesn't have access to server_c at all. I tried adding in RemoteForward lines to accomplish this:

```
host server_b
  Hostname 192.X.X.X
  User john
  IdentityFile /path/to/identity_file
  ForwardAgent yes
  RemoteForward 6880 server_c:22

Host server_a
  Hostname 172.X.X.X
  User john
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server_b
  RemoteForward 6880 localhost:6880
```

If I ssh directly into server_b, it seems like the remote forwarding to server_c is fine, but when I ssh straight into server_a from my laptop, access to server_c through the remote forward doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ProxyCommand is *not* the same as using `ssh server_b ssh server_a`. It lets the 2nd `ssh` client run *locally* and merely speak the SSH protocol through a tunnel.

So you don't need any forwarding parameters for the jump host, *only* for the final connection:

```
Host server_a
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server_b
    RemoteForward 6880 server_c:6880

Host server_b
    # no RemoteForward
    # no ForwardAgent, either!
```

---

Additionally, if you update your local OpenSSH client to 7.3 or later, you can use the `-J` option (aka ProxyJump) as a shortcut. For example, this is equal to the above config:

```
Host server_a
    ProxyJump server_b
    RemoteForward 6880 server_c:6880
```

The same in command line:

```
$ ssh -R 6880:server_c:6880 -J server_b server_a
```